# Finding Probability density function of $Y=\frac{1}{X^2+1}$ where $X \sim N[0,5]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I saw other similar questions on here, however, I can't figure this one out

Given $X \sim N[0,5],  $
$Y=\frac{1}{X^2+1}$

Find the density function $F_{Y}(y)$

$$P(Y\leq y) =P\left(\frac{1}{X^2+1}\leq y\right)\\=P\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1} \leq X\right) + P\left(X  \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1}\right)\\ =
P\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1} \leq X\right)+\left(1-P(X  < \sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1}\right).   $$

Is what am doing even correct?

Comment: $P(Y\leq y) =P(\frac{1}{X^2+1}\leq y)$ 

$\implies P(Y\leq y) =P(X \leq -\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1}) + P(X  \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comment,
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) = P(X \le - \sqrt{1/y - 1} ) + ( 1 - P ( X< \sqrt{1/y - 1}))
\end{align}
hence, to obtain the density you need to take derivative w.r.t. $y$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{\partial }{ \partial y }F_Y(y) \\
&=-f_X\left( - \sqrt{1/y - 1} \right)\frac{\partial }{ \partial y }\sqrt{1/y - 1} -  f_X \left( \sqrt{1/y - 1}\right)\frac{\partial }{ \partial y }\sqrt{1/y - 1}\\
& = \frac{1}{y^2\sqrt{2\pi 5}}\exp\left\{-\left( - \sqrt{1/y - 1} \right)^2/10\right\}(1/y - 1)^{-1/2}/2 \\ 
&+\frac{1}{y^2\sqrt{2\pi 5}}\exp\left\{-\left( - \sqrt{1/y - 1} \right)^2/10\right\}(1/y - 1)^{-1/2}/2\\
&=\frac{1}{y^2\sqrt{(1/y-1)2\pi 5}}\exp\left\{-\left(  1/y - 1 \right)/10\right\}, \quad \forall y>0
\end{align}

Comment: In the first line after differentiating, the second expression should be negative am right? since it's (1-P(...))

Comment: Yes, it becomes positive only after the inner diff. of $1/y$, that is $-1/y^2$